# reading data file into binary tree

Tags: structure, binary-search-tree, readfile

my program seems to only read part of the input data file

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "BST_ADT.h"

// Structure
typedef struct
    {
        char* name;
        char* market;
        char* initial;
        float stock;
    }COMPANY;

// Prototype Delarations
void addComp    (BST_TREE* list);
void deleteComp (BST_TREE* list);
void findStu   (BST_TREE* list);
void printList (BST_TREE* list);
int  compareStu (void* stu1, void* stu2);
void processStu (void* dataPtr);


int main (void)
{
// Local Definitions
   BST_TREE* list;

// Statements
   list = BST_Create(compareStu);
   addComp(list);
   deleteComp(list);
   findStu (list);
   printList(list);

    return 0;
}


/*===================== addComp =========================*/

void addComp    (BST_TREE* list)
{
// Local Declarations
   COMPANY* stuPtr;
   FILE* fp;
   char fileName[25];
   char buffer [100];
// Statements

   stuPtr = (COMPANY*)malloc (sizeof (COMPANY));
   stuPtr->name = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   stuPtr->market = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   stuPtr->initial = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));

   printf("Enter the file name: ");
           gets(fileName);
           fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
           if(fp == NULL)
           {
              printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
              exit(101);
           }
   while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
        {
            if (!stuPtr)
                printf("MEmory overflow!\n"), exit(101);
            sscanf(buffer, "%s  %s  %s  %f ", stuPtr->name, stuPtr->market, stuPtr->initial, &(stuPtr->stock));
            BST_Insert(list, stuPtr);
        } // end while
} //addStu

/*===================== deleteComp =========================*/

void deleteComp (BST_TREE* list)
{
// local definitions
   char name[100];
   char* namePtr = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   namePtr = name;
// statements
   printf("Enter Company name: ");
   scanf ("%39s", namePtr);

   if (!BST_Delete (list, namePtr))
       printf("ERROR: No Company: %0\n", *namePtr);
} // deleteStu
```

this is my input data from text file :

```
Target Corporation;      NYSE   TGT     44.14B  
PriceSmart, Inc.;        NASDAQ PSMT    721.96M   
Eastman Kodak Company;   NYSE   EK      5.14B  
Concord Camera Corp.;    NASDAQ LENS    25.43M  
Siemens AG (ADR);        NYSE   SI      123.13B  
3M Company;              NYSE   MMM     56.47B  
Toshiba Corporation;     OTC    TOSBF   24.43B  
Tyco International Ltd.; NYSE   TYC     19.91B  
Textron Inc.;            NYSE   TXT     13.90B  
PHH Corporation;         NYSE   PHH     1.11B  
Activision, Inc.;        NASDAQ ATVI    8.07B 
The Walt Disney Company; NYSE   DIS     61.27B
```

at the end of the addComp function

```
name contain 'The'
market contain 'Walt
initial contain 'Disney
and stock contain 6.09
```

this is not what the function was intended to do

instead, if this function was done right:

```
name should contain 'The Walt Disney Company'
market contain 'NYSE'
initial contain 'DIS'
and stock contain '61.27B
```

'

what did I do wrong with the addComp function? Was it necessary to use token in order to read these data into binary tree?

thank in advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf()` format specifier form `%s` to `%[^;];`.

`"%s"` ignores leading white space, then scans and saves non-whitespace text, finally adding a NUL.  `"%s"` saves "Target" in "Target Corporation;" - not what you want.

`" %[^;];"` ignores leading whitespace (the `' '` part) and then scans & saves for non-`';'` text and then scans for a `';'`, but not saving it.  `" %[^;];"` saves "Target Corporation" in "Target Corporation;"

Also recommend checking the result of `sscanf()`

```
if (4 != sscanf(buffer, " %[^;];  %s  %s  %f " ...) {
  ; // handle error
}
```